# Electromagnetic Force vs Magnetic Force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, inductance

I am confused between these two types of forces, what makes them different? For example, a moving ferromagnetic object in a solenoid that moves because of a magnetic field created. Which field would be applied here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete mathematical description of the *electromagnetic field* contains portions that are magnetic and portions which are electrostatic. Isolated cases of purely magnetic and electrostatic fields that are standing still or otherwise not changing in time are common. But when motion or change in field strength is involved, these two types of fields become intermingled and both fields must be included to describe what's going on. I am not clear what you are asking in the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, and for example an object is moving because of an applied current in a solenoid. The object (lets say it has magnets that are reacting to the field being created) that is moving is under the influence of the magnetic field being created. But it is a solenoid that makes it an electromagnet as well. Would that be an electromagnetic force being applied on the object or a magnetic force?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of your question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9b0J29OzAU This is a good example of what I am doing, what force is acting upon the magnets here? The magnetic force (which in-turn causes the battery to move) right?